# How do i make "unsign" work in cookie-signature

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

I am trying to sign cookie and unsign it by [cookie-signature](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie-signature).

but I attempt it along with Example, TypeError came up on my screen at `unsign` function.

```
TypeError: crypto.timingSafeEqual is not a function 
-----------------

var cookie = require('cookie-signature');

var val = cookie.sign('hello', 'tobiiscool');
val.should.equal('hello.DGDUkGlIkCzPz+C0B064FNgHdEjox7ch8tOBGslZ5QI');

var val = cookie.sign('hello', 'tobiiscool');
cookie.unsign(val, 'tobiiscool').should.equal('hello'); <- TypeError
cookie.unsign(val, 'luna').should.be.false;
```

How Can I use unsign function correctly?

※ my enviornment
・cookie-signature: v1.2.0
・Node: v12.19.0
・react: 16.14.0
・Next.js: v10

Comment: can you include your code snippet? Is hard to debug without it

Comment: Thank you to comment. I wrote code on question!

Comment: is there the error when you remove the `.should-equl` from then end of the unsign?

Comment: Yes, same error appears, even though removing the `.should-equl`.